# ng-if called within ng-included snippet re-calls default page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I don't understand why ng-if would cause default.html to fire when it is included on an html snippet page that is being loaded with ng-include?

partial/somePage.html

```
<div ng-repeat="note in notes">
    <div ng-include="note.htmlSnippet"></div>
</div>
```

One of many html snippet pages but this one includes an ng-if.

htmlSnippet.html

```
<div>
     <img ng-if="note.pk>0" src="note.filename" />
     <div ng-bind-html="note.message"></div>
</div>
```

The snippet templates all load from the same domain on the same path. If I remove the ng-if on the image the default page does not fire an extra time.  With it present as shown here, after the entire page is loaded something is calling back to the default.html (my root default) causing one additional hit on the server.  I looked at $routeProvider and the hit is not coming through there.  The note.message is pre-processed in my controller using $sce.trustAsHtml() and working perfectly. Also tried to pre-process the snippet page but still got the same results, the extra hit.

I'm completely stumped.

Comment: ng-include must get the path to the template, not the template itself. The rendering default template actually proves this. This is how it happens when the template path is wrong. Are you sure that the problem is in ng-if? Can you create some fiddle or plunkr example?

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind with being able to show my code example, that would mean that you would need to have access to the server logs.

In reference to just providing the path vs. the path/template.html in the ng-include directive, it works fine the way it is and if I omit the path, the browser gets stuck in a loop that talks about trying to load angular twice.  I relooked at the doc's for ng-include and I have it setup correctly as far as I can see.  The path and filename of the template are correctly referenced in my var note.htmlSnippet.

Answer (score 0):

The following line have problem:

```
<div ng-include="note.htmlSnippet"></div>
```

please changed it to:

```
<div ng-include src = "note.htmlSnippet" ></div>
```

There’s another issue is, following statement also wrong:

```
 <img ng-if="note.pk>0" src="note.filename" />
```

Using the statement will not be evaluated properly. You can change it to following:

```
 <img ng-if="note.pk>0" ng-src="{{note.filename}}" />
```

Make sure both changes described above are applied together.

Comment: Makes no difference, having ng-include="path/file" vs. src="path/file" if ng-if is included within the included page the server gets hit twice.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Is your image displaying properly?

Comment: Yes, if I include the ng-if or leave it out the image is displayed correctly.  The original idea was to have the ng-if to determine if an image related to the note and if not, display a default image.  In this design there were two <img> elements, one with a custom image and the other was the default fall back.  For now I just force all notes to have an image in the back end data and removed the ng-if.